# jquery mobile sliders - Prevent user from updating values

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider

I want to display some sliders on a jQuery Mobile page for showing my language skills. Obviously I dont want users to play with my sliders and change any value.
I am aware of the disable attribute 'disabled=disabled' or via JS '.slider("disable")' but that solution has a bad visual result on my sliders which I would like to avoid.

I managed to get it working by using the following code but I am after a DRY solution of my code that would allow me to affect any/all sliders on my page instead of targeting each IDs

The HTML:

```
<div id="languages">
  <label for="slider-fr">French (mother tongue):</label>
  <input name="slider-fr" id="slider-fr" min="0" max="200" value="200" type="range">
  <label for="slider-en">English:</label>
  <input name="slider-en" id="slider-en" min="0" max="200" value="190" type="range">
  <label for="slider-es">Spanish:</label>
  <input name="slider-es" id="slider-es" min="0" max="200" value="85" type="range">
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var slider_fr = $("#slider-fr").slider().val();
var slider_en = $("#slider-en").slider().val();
var slider_es = $("#slider-es").slider().val();
$("#slider-fr").change(function() {
    $(this).slider().val(slider_fr).slider("refresh");
});
$("#slider-en").change(function() {
    $(this).slider().val(slider_en).slider("refresh");
});
$("#slider-es").change(function() {
    $(this).slider().val(slider_es).slider("refresh");
});
```

Thank you for your help :)